# How do i use DESC limit 3 when i have joined two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have joinend two tables and it workes like it should do but now i want to use DESC limit, but i dont know where i should put it

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM posts INNER JOIN category ON posts.catid=category.id;';
$select_all_posts_query = mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

Comment: what is a DESC Limit? You can ORDER BY smth DESC, but not LIMIT DESC

Comment: but maybe you want something like `...ON posts.catid=category.id ORDER BY posts.id DESC LIMIT 3;`

Comment: oh wait, i just saw that the post get linked to the wrong category in the database table. How do i fix that?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to limit your results you can just add `LIMIT 3` to your query:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM posts INNER JOIN category ON posts.catid=category.id; LIMIT 3';
$select_all_posts_query = mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

Alternatively, if you are also trying to order your results is descending order you'll need to add and `ORDER BY` to the query as well:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM posts INNER JOIN category ON posts.catid=category.id; ORDER BY posts.id DESC LIMIT 3';
$select_all_posts_query = mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

Comment: when doing it like that it accuelly changes the id of the post to the id of the category. All i want is to show the name of the category that is assingned to the post.

Screenshot: https://ibb.co/Yfc6Gb0

Example title: LOREM IPSUM 2 | CATEGORY WILL SHOW HERE

Comment: Okay, I've updated it. Is that what you were referring too @PerJohansson?

Comment: Sadly doesnt help it still change the id of the post url for exemple (http://localhost/post.php?id=1) to the id of the category in the category table.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM posts INNER JOIN category ON posts.catid=category.id ORDER BY posts.catid=category.id DESC LIMIT 3 ';
$select_all_posts_query = mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

Comment: Now it the same id on all of them.

Comment: Try this, 

$query = 'SELECT * FROM posts INNER JOIN category ON posts.catid=category.id ORDER BY posts.catid DESC LIMIT 3 ';
$select_all_posts_query = mysqli_query($link, $query);